# Production deployment issue: Next 13 APP router and supabase resulting in 404

Tags: next.js, next-auth, supabase

I'm building a website with **Next 13 APP router** and **supabase**. and it's doing well, but, for some reason, when I deploy it to production I get 404 on two situations:

Probably it's some misconfiguration since I just started with this stack. I already spent too much time trying to solve it, and **even ChatGPT couldn't, so... fuck it**.

When I access `/highlines` it gets 404 on id 1 and 2, and these exist on my database, on the local environment it returns successfully, and I'm using the same keys.

I didn't understand why It fetched those dynamic routes when accessing this one, it shouldn't fire just when I access `/highlines/[id]`?

[image]

And when I access `highlines/[id]` I get a similar error and that default 404 error page.

[image]

### Some code for context.

First I initialize my supabase client on `src/lib/supabaseClient.ts`.

```js
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

import type { Database } from "../types/supabase";

export type Tables = Database["public"]["Tables"];

if (
  !process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL ||
  !process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
) {
  throw new Error("Missing Supabase env variables");
}

export default createClient<Database>(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
);
```

Then import it on `src/app/highlines/page.tsx`

```js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

import supabase from "~/lib/supabaseClient";
import Highline from "~/components/Highline";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default async function page() {
  const { data: highlines } = await supabase.from("highline").select("*");

  if (!highlines) {
    return <div>Carregando...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <section className="mx-auto max-w-screen-xl flex-wrap gap-4 px-4 py-8 md:flex lg:px-6 lg:py-16">
      <div className="min-w-[384px] flex-1">
        <h2
          className="mb-4 text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
          style={inter.style}
        >
          SETOR VEREDÃO
        </h2>
        <p className="font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          Setor da cachoeira veredinha. Tem acesso para o Highline mais alto do
          festival e também à cachoeira pra curtir aquela vibe
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-[1_0_0%] flex-col items-center space-y-9 ">
        {highlines.map((highline) => (
          <Highline key={highline.id} highline={highline} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

The `Highline` component looks like:

```js
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import type { Tables } from "~/lib/supabaseClient";

interface Props {
  highline: Tables["highline"]["Row"];
}

function Highline({ highline }: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 sm:w-128">
      <motion.div layoutId="image" className="relative block h-72 w-full">
        <Image
          src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400"
          alt="highline"
          fill
          className="object-cover object-center"
        />
      </motion.div>
      <div className="p-5">
        <a href="#">
          <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
            {highline.name}
          </h5>
        </a>
        <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so
          far, in reverse chronological order.
        </p>
        <Link
          href={`/highlines/${highline.id}`}
          className="inline-flex items-center rounded-lg bg-blue-700 px-3 py-2 text-center text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
        >
          Ver detalhes
          <svg
            aria-hidden="true"
            className="-mr-1 ml-2 h-4 w-4"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              fillRule="evenodd"
              d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
              clipRule="evenodd"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Highline;
```

So, when the user clicks on a button it's redirected to `/highlines/${highline.id}`. This route maps to `app/highlines/[id]/page.tsx`

```js
"use client";

import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Image from "next/image";

import supabase from "~/lib/supabaseClient";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Tabs from "~/components/tabs/Tabs";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

interface Params {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

export default async function page({ params }: Params) {
  const { data: highline, error } = await supabase
    .from("highline")
    .select("*")
    .eq("id", params.id)
    .single();
  console.log({
    highline,
    error,
  });
  if (!highline) return null;

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto flex w-full max-w-screen-lg flex-1 items-center justify-center px-4 py-8 lg:px-6 lg:py-16">
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
        className="flex min-h-[32rem] w-full max-w-screen-md flex-wrap-reverse rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow-2xl dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800"
      >
        <div className="mb-6 w-full px-2 lg:mb-0 lg:w-1/2 lg:py-6 lg:pr-10">
          <h1 className="my-4 text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
            {highline.name}
          </h1>
          <Tabs
            tabs={[
              {
                id: "info",
                label: "Informações",
              },
              {
                id: "reviews",
                label: "Reviews",
              },
              {
                id: "ranking",
                label: "Ranking",
              },
            ]}
            highline={highline}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="relative h-64 w-full rounded lg:h-auto lg:w-1/2">
          <Image
            src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400"
            alt="highline"
            fill
            className="object-cover object-center"
          />
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please, let me know if there is any additional information that I can put here, I'm developing this project for a highline festival for free, just for the community! I do have not much time, and I really want to make it.

https://www.instagram.com/festivalchooselife/

**Thx in advance.**